# java: EOFException using BufferedReader with CompressorInputStream

Tags: java

I'm executing the following code which reads a compressed file and prints it out to console.

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
CompressorInputStream comis = new CompressorStreamFactory().createCompressorInputStream(bis);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(comis));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readline())!=null){
 System.out.println(line);
}
```

It reads the file fine, but prints the following exception at the end.

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.read(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:273)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at DecompressTest.main(DecompressTest.java:44)
```

Is there a way to use BufferedReader's readLine() method without getting this error?

Comment: you can add a `try - catch` block!

Comment: It's there. I didn't include it in the snippet above. In fact, the exception is thrown from the stack trace printed from the catch block